# ipv6 global address missing after link flap

Tags: ipv6, ifconfig

> > in linux/ubuntu after the link flap on an interface the global ipv6 address is flushed out & not seen in ifconfig. Any kernel patch/sysctl to retain the ipv6 address configured after the link flap.?
> >
> > Also this behavior is different than ipv4 address on the same interface where the ipv4 address is retained across the link flap, any particular reason why this is the behavior for ipv6 address only.?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:99:03:c2  
          inet addr:192.168.136.160  Bcast:192.168.136.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe99:3c2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ip -6 addr add dead::1/120 dev eth0
root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state  UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:0c:29:99:03:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.136.160/24 brd 192.168.136.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 dead::1/120 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe99:3c2/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ifconfig eth0 down
root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:99:03:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.136.160/24 brd 192.168.136.255 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ifconfig eth0 up
root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:99:03:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.136.160/24 brd 192.168.136.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe99:3c2/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@ubuntu:/home/sharb# ifconfig eth0 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:99:03:c2  
  inet addr:192.168.136.160  Bcast:192.168.136.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe99:3c2/64 Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:48116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:13355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:65293789 (65.2 MB)  TX bytes:1052427 (1.0 MB)"
```

Comment: What is in`/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @Dubu

/etc/network/interfaces does not have anything for this eth

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the default setting of the attribute keep_addr_on_down.
Please check [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.6.1#n1571). You could test it by setting this attribute to 1 and flap the link again.